# How can I export the whiteboard text saved into a .ucf (Cisco webex) into something I can read?

Tags: text, format, cisco, webex

I just ended a Webex meeting. During the meeting, I took notes on a whiteboard within the Webex meeting. After the meeting I saved all, both as pdf and again in [ucf format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Communication_Format). The pdf rendered the text as an image, so I cannot copy and paste it into another document format.
The UCF, when opened in Notepad, seems promising, since it does contain the text, but it has a lot of "noise" too. There must be a simpler way to get the text - just the text - out of the ucf file.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Cisco Webex whiteboards *are images*. So, unfortunately, no way to convert the UCF to text.

Per my support team: "The whiteboard contents cannot be saved as text, it will always save as an image file whether you use UCF or PDF formats, as it is an image. "

Bummer!